# Jetty or Tomcat for small Linode

Tags: tomcat, jetty

my [site](http://www.dealmer.com) is running on [linode](http://linode.com). I have got 380+ MB RAM. I need to run the web server + Solr + Postgres + memcached on the same space.

Which is best Jetty or Tomcat? It is simple, plain search server. We use [Pylons](http://www.pylonshq.com/) for development.

Comment: I refered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302977/tomcat-vs-jetty. I don't understand low maintenance cost. Is it takes less time to configure? I need small foot print for the search server

Comment: +1 on the question, just because i found out i can can more for my money by switching to linode from rapidvps!

Comment: Can you comment on how the present status is on Jetty vs Tomcat? I am also planning a 512 MB slice for Solr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetty can be set up to load only the features you need. 
For example you can turn off session support.

I think Jetty is better in general case either, see [Jetty vs Tomcat](http://www.webtide.com/choose/jetty.jsp) comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I have used both, and found that Jetty was a heck of a lot easier to set up on CentOS. However, I have one server running with Tomcat, and it's been rock solid (on a 512MB Linode).

I've seen a tiny bit of performance improvement on Jetty for a high-volume search server, but it's nothing that would make me choose it over Tomcat for performance reasons alone...