# Specific differences between Jetty and Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jetty

I have done some research on this topic but have been unable to progress any further.  Technical answers would be best but everything will help.

Why does tomcat use more memory than Jetty?
Why is jetty more scalable and better at serving static content?

What are the differences in API's and underlying tools between these containers?

I am doing a report on how these tools differ but have only come up with similarities, any underlying differences would be greatly helpful as I do not know where to look.  I am not very familiar with these topics but I can research the answers you give.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302977/tomcat-vs-jetty?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329254/tomcat-7-vs-jetty?rq=1

Comment: These do not answer my specific questions. The title is very similar however